# python - sort strings in list by skipping first 4 lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

My list looks this:

```
l = ['abcdbcex', 'abcdbc1fz', 'abcdcd11', 'abcd11a5']
```

I want to sort it in a way that it will become:

```
l = ['abcd11a5', 'abczbc1fz', 'abcfbcex', 'abcecd11']
```

So sort in ascending order, but skipping first 4 letters, also skipping everything after the 7th letter.

I have tried doing: `sorted(list, key=lambda x:x[:4])`

but this does not skip the first 4 letters, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You confused the slice, it's `x[4:]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo typo in the question

Comment: Still, notice the location of the `:`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo ah yes thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call it list, it's a reserved word. THis does work though:

```
sorted(xlist,key=lambda s: s[4:])

['abcd11a5', 'abcdbc1fz', 'abcdbcex', 'abcdcd11']
```